# MySQL auto increment to 8 digits

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database I have an auto increment column which saves the ID as an 8 digit number.

However the digits are starting at `00000114`, Is there a way to start these at another figure  of `82925298'

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

> To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that
>   value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:
>
> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 82925298;

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 82925298;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 82925298;`